# Is there a way to recompile project only if gradle dependency changed a public class that is used in my project?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management, gradle-dependencies

Let's say there are modules **A** & **B**.

A depends on B `implementation(project(":B"))`, let's say by using `bClassObj.doSomething("hello")`.

So we have:

```
 BClass.kt

`fun doSomething(salute: String)`
```

If **B** modifies ANY class, then it will force **A** to be recompiled, which is not desired because nothing changed for the matter of A.

Is there a default way to achieve that only A is recompiled if the API it uses is affected? (making method private, changing signature, removing method or class, etc)

Comment: I don't think gradle will do this kind of deep analysis, it's looking at file changes as far as I'm aware. And a file change in B can mean that something in A needs to change. Maybe split B into smaller libraries if you can or buy faster hardware :)